# Java: get greatest common divisor

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I have seen that such a function exists for `BigInteger`, i.e. [`BigInteger#gcd`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#gcd%28java.math.BigInteger%29). Are there other functions in Java which also work for other types (`int`, `long` or `Integer`)? It seems this would make sense as `java.lang.Math.gcd` (with all kinds of overloads) but it is not there. Is it somewhere else?

---

(Don't confuse this question with "how do I implement this myself", please!)

Comment: Why is the accepted answer one that tells you how to implement it yourself - although wrapping an existing implementation? =)

Comment: I agree with your observation. GCD should a class with a bunch of overloaded static methods that takes in two numbers and gives it's gcd. And it should be part of the java.math package.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

For int and long, as primitives, not really.  For Integer, it is possible someone wrote one.

Given that BigInteger is a (mathematical/functional) superset of int, Integer, long, and Long, if you need to use these types, convert them to a BigInteger, do the GCD, and convert the result back.

```
private static int gcdThing(int a, int b) {
    BigInteger b1 = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
    BigInteger gcd = b1.gcd(b2);
    return gcd.intValue();
}
```

Comment: `BigInteger.valueOf(a).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(b)).intValue()` is much better.

Comment: Some benchmarks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570890/java-get-greatest-common-divisor-which-method-is-better

Comment: If this function is called often (i.e. millions of times) you shouldn't convert int or long to BigInteger. A function using only primitive values will likely be an order of magnitude faster. Check the other answers.

Comment: @Bhanu Pratap Singh To avoid casting or truncation, it's better to use separate methods for int and long. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This not only doesn't answer the question (where is gcd for int or long in Java) but the proposed implementation is pretty unefficient.  This should not be the accepted answer.  As far as I know the Java runtime doesn't have it, but it exists in third party libraries.

Answer (score 163):

As far as I know, there isn't any built-in method for primitives. But something as simple as this should do the trick:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b) {
   if (b==0) return a;
   return gcd(b,a%b);
}
```

You can also one-line it if you're into that sort of thing:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b) { return b==0 ? a : gcd(b, a%b); }
```

It should be noted that there is absolutely *no* difference between the two as they compile to the same byte code.

Comment: As far as I can tell it works fine. I just ran 100,000 random numbers though both methods and they agreed each time.

Comment: It's Euclidean algorithm... It's very old and proven right.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Yep, I can kind of see it but I need more time to work through it.  I like it.

Comment: @Albert, well you could always try it out with a generic type and see if it works. I dunno just a thought, but the algorithm is there for you to experiment with. As far as some standard library or class, I've never seen one. You will still need to specify when you create the object that it is an int, long, etc.. though.

Comment: @Albert, well, although Matt provided an implementation, you yourself could make it work in a, as you put is, "more generic" way, no? :)

Comment: @Albert, yes I misunderstood your question, and it seems you misunderstood my reply as well: I know you didn't ask **how** to implement this. But, to answer your question whether this is implemented in Java: it isn't (at least, not the way you are asking for).

Comment: @Albert could you give an example? In all languages i've dealt with you have to tell the program what type of something you are working with. It may not be as clear as day and the compiler may take care of that work for you, but I'm pretty sure there is nothing like that.

Comment: @Albert, I never mentioned '(Java's) generics'. I meant that the overloading of these methods could be done by you yourself (even more so since the algorithm has been posted, even if you were already aware of said algorithm).

Comment: @Albert yea, ive gone through that. And you specify types in haskell, So i guess i still don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: No, hence why i posted one. But you can create a generic one if wanted to. Like stated above, you will have to tell it what it is though when you create an object to use that. public <E> GCD(<E> a, <E> b). GCD<Int> newGCD = new GCD<Int>(); while this may not be not be 100% correct, as i haven't touched java in years, but this should be someone correct and just to point out you can have a generic type.

Comment: Big disclaimer on this -- if you have negative numbers, it may return a NEGATIVE GCD! =\  Works, otherwise. =)

Comment: Lol that when you understand Math trick from a piece of a Code faster than from crappy formulas and math calculation examples over the internet!

Answer (score 36):

Or the Euclidean algorithm for calculating the GCD...

```
public int egcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0)
        return b;

    while (b != 0) {
        if (a > b)
            a = a - b;
        else
            b = b - a;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: This is absolutely not what I was asking for.

Comment: In this case, you had not specified that you didn't want alternative implementations since one didn't exist. Only later did you edit your post not looking for implementations. I believe others had answered "no" more than adequately.

Comment: This would be slow if a is very large and b is small.  The '%' solutions would be much faster.

Comment: This would slow even if difference between a and b would small. I test this now with a = Long.MAX_VALUE and b = Long.MAX_VALUE - 3 and i wait to result for several minutes

Answer (score 13):

Unless I have Guava, I define like this:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
  return a == 0 ? b : gcd(b % a, a);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Jakarta Commons Math has exactly that.

[ArithmeticUtils.gcd(int p, int q)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html#gcd(int,%20int))

Answer (score 11):

Use Guava [`LongMath.gcd()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#gcd(long,%20long)) and [`IntMath.gcd()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#gcd(int,%20int))

Comment: Interestingly Guava doesn't use the Euclidean "modulo" method but the binary GCD algorithm that they claim to be 40% faster.  It is safe to say it is pretty efficient and well-tested.

Comment: These links are dead now, it seems the new documentation lives @ https://guava.dev/releases/30.1.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/package-summary.html

Answer (score 7):

You can use this implementation of [Binary GCD algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_GCD_algorithm)

```
public class BinaryGCD {

public static int gcd(int p, int q) {
    if (q == 0) return p;
    if (p == 0) return q;

    // p and q even
    if ((p & 1) == 0 && (q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q >> 1) << 1;

    // p is even, q is odd
    else if ((p & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q);

    // p is odd, q is even
    else if ((q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p, q >> 1);

    // p and q odd, p >= q
    else if (p >= q) return gcd((p-q) >> 1, q);

    // p and q odd, p < q
    else return gcd(p, (q-p) >> 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int q = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    System.out.println("gcd(" + p + ", " + q + ") = " + gcd(p, q));
}
```

}

From http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/BinaryGCD.java.html

Comment: It's a variation of Stein's algorithm which exploits that on most machines, shifting is a relatively cheap operation. It's a standard algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

Some implementations here are not working correctly if both numbers are negative. gcd(-12, -18) is 6, not -6.

So an absolute value should be returned, something like

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return Math.abs(a);
    }
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

Comment: One edge case for this is if both `a` and `b` are `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, you'll get `Integer.MIN_VALUE` back as the result, which is negative. This may be acceptable. The problem being that gcd(-2^31, -2^31)=2^31, but 2^31 can't be expressed as an integer.

Comment: I'd also recommend using `if(a==0 || b==0) return Math.abs(a+b);` so that the behaviour is truly symmetric for zero arguments.

Answer (score 3):

we can use recursive function for find gcd

```
public class Test
{
 static int gcd(int a, int b)
    {
        // Everything divides 0 
        if (a == 0 || b == 0)
           return 0;

        // base case
        if (a == b)
            return a;

        // a is greater
        if (a > b)
            return gcd(a-b, b);
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a = 98, b = 56;
        System.out.println("GCD of " + a +" and " + b + " is " + gcd(a, b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int gcd(int num1, int num2) { 
    int max = Math.abs(num1);
    int min = Math.abs(num2);

    while (max > 0) {
        if (max < min) {
            int x = max;
            max = min;
            min = x;
        }
        max %= min;
    }

    return min;
}
```

This method uses the Euclid’s algorithm to get the "Greatest Common Divisor" of two integers. It receives two integers and returns the gcd of them. just that easy!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 1.5 or later then this is an iterative binary GCD algorithm which uses [`Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros%28int%29) to reduce the number of checks and iterations required.

```
public class Utils {
    public static final int gcd( int a, int b ){
        // Deal with the degenerate case where values are Integer.MIN_VALUE
        // since -Integer.MIN_VALUE = Integer.MAX_VALUE+1
        if ( a == Integer.MIN_VALUE )
        {
            if ( b == Integer.MIN_VALUE )
                throw new IllegalArgumentException( "gcd() is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE" );
            return 1 << Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( Math.abs(b) );
        }
        if ( b == Integer.MIN_VALUE )
            return 1 << Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( Math.abs(a) );

        a = Math.abs(a);
        b = Math.abs(b);
        if ( a == 0 ) return b;
        if ( b == 0 ) return a;
        int factorsOfTwoInA = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(a),
            factorsOfTwoInB = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(b),
            commonFactorsOfTwo = Math.min(factorsOfTwoInA,factorsOfTwoInB);
        a >>= factorsOfTwoInA;
        b >>= factorsOfTwoInB;
        while(a != b){
            if ( a > b ) {
                a = (a - b);
                a >>= Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( a );
            } else {
                b = (b - a);
                b >>= Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros( b );
            }
        }
        return a << commonFactorsOfTwo;
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class UtilsTest {
    @Test
    public void gcdUpToOneThousand(){
        for ( int x = -1000; x <= 1000; ++x )
            for ( int y = -1000; y <= 1000; ++y )
            {
                int gcd = Utils.gcd(x, y);
                int expected = BigInteger.valueOf(x).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(y)).intValue();
                assertEquals( expected, gcd );
            }
    }

    @Test
    public void gcdMinValue(){
        for ( int x = 0; x < Integer.SIZE-1; x++ ){
            int gcd = Utils.gcd(Integer.MIN_VALUE,1<<x);
            int expected = BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(1<<x)).intValue();
            assertEquals( expected, gcd );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar to MutableBigInteger.binaryGcd(int,int), unfortunately the latter is not accessible. But cool anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it somewhere else?

[Apache!](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils.html) - it has both gcd and lcm, so cool!

However, due to profoundness of their implementation, it's slower compared to simple hand-written version (if it matters).

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
import scanner and instantiate scanner class;
declare your method with two parameters
declare a third variable;
set condition;
swap the parameter values if condition is met;
set second conditon based on result of first condition;
divide and assign remainder to the third variable;
swap the result;
in the main method, allow for user input;
Call the method;

*/
public class gcf {
    public static void main (String[]args){//start of main method
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);//allow for user input
        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");//prompt
        int a = input.nextInt();//initial user input
        System.out.println("Please enter a second interger: ");//prompt
        int b = input.nextInt();//second user input


       Divide(a,b);//call method
    }
   public static void Divide(int a, int b) {//start of your method

    int temp;
    // making a greater than b
    if (b > a) {
         temp = a;
         a = b;
         b = temp;
    }

    while (b !=0) {
        // gcd of b and a%b
        temp = a%b;
        // always make a greater than b
        a =b;
        b =temp;

    }
    System.out.println(a);//print to console
  }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate with an explanation how this might help ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this method that I created when I was 14 years old.

```
    public static int gcd (int a, int b) {
        int s = 1;
        int ia = Math.abs(a);//<-- turns to absolute value
        int ib = Math.abs(b);
        if (a == b) {
            s = a;
        }else {
            while (ib != ia) {
                if (ib > ia) {
                    s = ib - ia;
                    ib = s;
                }else { 
                    s = ia - ib;
                    ia = s;
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those GCD functions provided by [Commons-Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) and [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/MathExplained) have some differences.

- Commons-Math throws an [`ArithematicException.class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) only for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

  - Otherwise, handles the value as an absolute value.
- Guava throws an `IllegalArgumentException.class` for any negative values.

Answer (score -3):

The % going to give us the gcd Between two numbers, it means:-
% or mod of big_number/small_number are =gcd,
and we write it on java like this  `big_number % small_number`.

EX1: for two integers

```
  public static int gcd(int x1,int x2)
    {
        if(x1>x2)
        {
           if(x2!=0)
           {
               if(x1%x2==0)     
                   return x2;
                   return x1%x2;
                   }
           return x1;
           }
          else if(x1!=0)
          {
              if(x2%x1==0)
                  return x1;
                  return x2%x1;
                  }
        return x2;
        }
```

EX2: for three integers

```
public static int gcd(int x1,int x2,int x3)
{

    int m,t;
    if(x1>x2)
        t=x1;
    t=x2;
    if(t>x3)
        m=t;
    m=x3;
    for(int i=m;i>=1;i--)
    {
        if(x1%i==0 && x2%i==0 && x3%i==0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, e.g. `gcd(42, 30)` should be `6` but it is `12` by your example. But 12 is not a divisor of 30 and neither of 42. You should call `gcd` recursively. See the answer by Matt or look on Wikipedia for the Euclidean algorithm.