# Writing a method that finds the Greatest Common Divisor between 2 integers USING RECURSION?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, methods, recursion

Euclid's algorithm tells us how to compute the *greatest common divisor* (GCD) of two
positive integers `a` and `b`. Using Euclid's algorithm, to find the GCD of `206` and `40` (for
example), first find the remainder when `206` is divided by `40`. Then find the GCD of `40`
and this remainder (which turns out to be `6`), using the same idea again. When you reach
the point where the second number is `0`, the first number will be the GCD of `206` and `40`
that you were looking for, as shown below.

```
gcd(206, 40)
= gcd(40, 6)
= gcd(6, 4)
= gcd(4, 2)
= gcd(2, 0)
= 2
```

Write a method called `gcd`. YOU MUST USE RECURSION IN THIS METHOD (calling the method within the method). This method should use Euclid's
algorithm to return the greatest common divisor of two positive integers.

So basically I don't know how to do this WITH (sorry i wrote without before on accident) recursion..
Please help! :( I have been stuck on this for so long.. I wrote a method, but it doesn't use recursion and it only woks for the given `206` and `40`..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: get greatest common divisor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009198/java-get-greatest-common-divisor)

Comment: Show us the method you wrote.

Comment: I'm voting this question down because it's just a well-hidden "gimme teh codez".  A recursive Java implementation of GCD is just one Google-request away.

Comment: Wait wait wait, you need to use recursion, but you don't know how to do it **without** recursion? Then what's the problem? Use recursion like you're supposed to. Or do you mean that you don't know how to do it **with** recursion?

Comment: Please edit the question back to how it was!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simple to implement using recursion:

```
public int gcd(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

The algorithm is explained in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you sir. The wiki page helped. Wasn't aware all of that info was on there.