# Print out the value of a Java Method

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class GCD {

public static int GCD(int m, int n){
    if (n==0) return m;
    callCount(1);
    return GCD(n,m%n);
}

public static int callCount(int n){
    int s = 0;
    s+=n;
    return s;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    callCount(0);
    System.out.println(GCD(10, 15));
    System.out.println(callCount());
    }
}
```

Once GCD has finished I would like to print out how many times GCD was invoked with the method callCount. I think I am going about callcount completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to print out how many times it had to go through GCD but I wasn't sure the correct approach.

Comment: You could use `BigInteger` if so required: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4009230/2591612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
public class GCD {

private static int callCount = 0;

public static int GCD(int m, int n){
  if (n==0) return m;
  callCount++;
  return GCD(n,m%n);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(GCD(10, 15));
    System.out.println(callCount);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to make `s` a static int, rather than declare it locally

```
public class GCD {

    static int s = 0;
```

Comment: And why keep the method to count, its useless

Answer (score -1):

Create a public static variable count, and increase it at the end of the callCount() method.
Everytime it will be invoked the veriable will be increased thus showing you how many times it was invoked.