# Check if an array contains an integer that can divide all the other integers

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a function which returns `true` only if a given array contains at least one integer that can divide all the other integers. Otherwise returns `false`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
     public static boolean check(int[] arr) {
         int n = arr.length;
         boolean res = false;
         
         for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {             
             for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
                if(arr[i]%arr[j]!=0 && arr[j]%arr[i]!=0) break;
                
                if(j == n-1) res = true;
            }
         }
         return res;
     }

     public static void main(String []args){
        int[] arr = {4,2,6,8};
        System.out.println(check(arr)); // -> true
        
        int[] arr2 = {4,3,6,8};
        System.out.println(check(arr2)); // -> false
     }
```

Seems like my code provides the correct output, but I want to know a better approach without having to use nested for loops.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I *think* if there is such an integer, it must be the smallest, so take the min() and then check if it divides all the numbers.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009198/java-get-greatest-common-divisor#4009247 You're looking for the greatest common divisor (GCD).

Comment: @gouessej - If you want to solve it using GCD, it will not only be about finding GCD but also checking if the GCD is present in the array. However, it will be a too complicated way because you will have to find the GCD of not only two numbers but of all the numbers.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash You're right, my suggestion is over-complicated.

Comment: @MarkLavin I think you want the minimum positive absolute value rather than just the minimum. Zero can be divided by any number.

Answer (score 3):

## `Stream` API

For a cleaner solution, I would use `Stream` API.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static boolean check(int[] arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return false;
        int[] arrClone = arr.clone();
        Arrays.setAll(arrClone, i -> Math.abs(arrClone[i]));
        Supplier<IntStream> streamSupplier = () -> Arrays.stream(arrClone);
        int min = streamSupplier.get().min().getAsInt();
        return streamSupplier.get().filter(n -> min != 0).allMatch(n -> n % min == 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 4, 2, 6, 8 };
        System.out.println(check(arr)); // -> true

        int[] arr2 = { 4, 3, 6, 8 };
        System.out.println(check(arr2)); // -> false

        System.out.println(check(new int[] { 1, -5 }));
        System.out.println(check(new int[] {}));
        System.out.println(check(new int[] { 0, -5 }));
        System.out.println(check(new int[] { 0, 5 }));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
true
false
true
true
```

Learn more about the `Stream` API from [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams.html) and [Part 2: Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

Comment: Excellent, far better than my suggestion. Good job, this is the kind of answer I expected ;) You use the Stream API correctly.

Comment: Doesn't work for e.g. `{0, 1}`, or `{1, -5}`, or `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
public static boolean check(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr)
        .filter(i -> i != 0)
        .map(Math::abs)
        .min().stream()
        .anyMatch(min -> IntStream.of(arr)
            .allMatch(i -> i % min == 0));
}

public static void main(String []args){
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {4, 2, 6, 8}));  // true
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {4, 3, 6, 8}));  // false
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {-4, 2, 6, 8})); // true
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {4, 0, 6, 8}));  // false
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {2, 0, 6, 8}));  // true
   System.out.println(check(new int[] {}));            // false
}
```

output:

```
true
false
true
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the `List`.
So you'll sort the numbers in ascending order, with the first number being the smallest using the `Collections.sort()` method.
Then, just take the first number and check if dividing the next number by the first one returns the remainder 0. If there is a remainder other than 0 in the middle of the `for`, it means that there is no number capable of dividing all the integers, so it will stop the `for` and `return false`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class YourClass {

    public static boolean check(List<Integer> arr) {
        boolean res = true;

        Collections.sort(arr);
        int pri;

        if(arr.size() > 0){
           pri = arr.get(0);

           for(int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++){
                if(arr.get(i) % pri != 0){
                    res = false;
                    break;
                }
           }
        }else{
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check(Arrays.asList(4,2,6,8)));

        //or
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4, 3, 6, 8);
        System.out.println(check(list));
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no need to sort a list to get its minimum element.

Answer (score 0):

Number you looking for is smallest number greater than `0`. So you don't need nested loops.

Find the smallest number:

- if it is `1`, you have your answer.
- if not, you need to go through the list only once.

Comment: Well idea of "divisible by" is usually applied to natural numbers, but it is easy to extend this algorithm to negative numbers.

Comment: "Number you looking for is smallest number greater than 1" greater than zero, surely?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes. I thought that 1 is usually special case and had brain glitch.

Comment: @user16320675 Ok. I'm so old that negative numbers wasn't invented when I studied that, so I have problems with them sometimes.