# Calculating degrees to radians in terms of pi

Tags: java, calculator, degrees, radians

I made a code converting degrees to radians following my teacher's format but I want to try to make it in terms of pi. Right now when I plug in 30 as my degrees the output is a loooong decimal but I want it to come out as pi/6. Is there a way to keep the pi symbol in the output?

This is my current code:

```
    public static double convertDeg(double deg)
    {
        double rad = deg * (Math.PI/180);
        return rad;
    }
```

and

```
System.out.println("Degrees to radians: "+Calculate.convertDeg(30));
```

The output is: "Degrees to radians: 0.5235987755982988"

Comment: Why not just leave PI out of the equation completely.  Compute `180/deg` and then print "Pi/" followed by the result of your calculation.

Comment: Or you want `pi / 2` `pi / 3`, `pi / 6` depending on specific results? Like 270 deg -> `3 pi / 2`, 120 deg -> `2 pi / 3` etc?

Comment: Your function returns just a number.  Per your print statement, you are assuming that your function returns radians. To satisfy those two requirements, you want to do exactly what you're showing above.  You can't return a decimal value that includes PI.  Why would you want to?  If you don't like displaying so many digits, there is an easy way to deal with that in Python.

Comment: I would like the calculator to be able to simplify the answer, keeping the pi in the numerator (keeping it a fraction instead of a decimal unless that's not a thing)

Comment: It's not a standard thing in Python.  It's not a standard thing in programming in general.  If you aren't being asked explicitly to do this, I would forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set formatting up to convert degrees to radians with pi out of the box in java, but you can write your own function to do this.

```
We know that 
360 degrees = 2 * PI   radians =>
180 degrees = PI       radians =>
1   degree  = PI / 180 radians =>

Therefore
X degrees = PI * (X / 180) radians

In case degrees is an integer value 
  we can simplify a fraction X / 180
  if gcd(X, 180) > 1, gcd -- the greater common divider.
  X / 180 = (X / gcd(X, 180)) / (180 / gcd(X, 180))

The code is something like this (don't forget to check corner cases):

String formatDegreesAsFractionWithPI(int degrees) {
  int gcd = gcd(degrees, 180);
  return "(" + (degrees / gcd) + " / " + (180 / gcd) + ") * PI"
}

int gcd(int a, int b) = { ... }

In case degrees is a floating point number, 
  the problem is more complicated and my advice 
  is to read about 'converting decimal floating 
  point number to integers fraction'.
```

Related questions: [gcd in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009198/java-get-greatest-common-divisor), [convert float to fraction (maybe works)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748560/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-java)